# How to turn my cursor to an left or right icon, when hovering on the left side or right of my slider?

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

I have a team slider on this website: http://hedge.cloud-2.co.uk/ (This is us page - which is the final slide).

When hovering over the employees image on the slider, I need the cusor to either turn to an arrow pointing left/right depending on where the cursor is positioned on the image.

Similar to this: https://www.rouvre.com/fr/gallery/9/portraits/670

Anybody know of a js library for this or anything?

Answer (score 0):

https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-manipulate-cursor-appearance-with-css--cms-31825 - Heres a tutorial on how to do it. Daymm wish I found this earlier before posting my question!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that just using CSS!

[From Mozilla Docs:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Basic_User_Interface/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property)

> For example, the following value would be allowed:
>
> cursor: url(foo.cur), url(http://www.example.com/bar.gif), auto;

You basically provide the image you want and it will replace the cursor. Use the code above and just replace the URL with the image you want.